# Blanket implementation of trait using regular and "negative" bounds

Tags: rust, traits

I want to "hide" a vector type using a trait `Vector`.
I also want this trait to provide a method to push values to implementers via a string reference.
Ideally, I'd like to use the `FromStr` trait to automatically implement the `Vector` trait. Here you have an example (it does not compile):

```rust
use std::str::FromStr;

trait Vector {
    fn try_push(&mut self, val: &str) -> Result<(), ()>;
}

struct MyVec<T>(Vec<T>);

impl<T: FromStr> Vector for MyVec<T> {
    fn try_push(&mut self, val: &str) -> Result<(), ()> {
        match T::from_str(val) {
            Ok(val) => {
                self.0.push(val);
                Ok(())
            },
            Err(_) => Err(()),
        }
    }
}

impl<T: !FromStr> Vector for MyVec<T> {
    fn try_push(&mut self, val: &str) -> Result<(), ()> {
        Err(())
    }
}
```

The compiler complains because *"negative bounds are not supported"*. I am aware that negative bounds are not currently supported by stable Rust, but cannot figure out how to implement what I want. Can anyone suggest me the most appropriate way to implement this pattern?

Comment: Why do you need the second part? You are attempting to reduce a compilation error down to a runtime error; why? Isn't catching this error at compile time better?

Comment: I want this method to be optional. As it is an optional feature, I'd like to have a "default" implementation which just returns an error. If users want to use it, then they will need to make sure that their values implement the FromStr trait.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you wish to hide the Vector type?

Comment: I want to implement a Rust crate for simulating models using the DEVS formalism. Basically, models use "ports" to send messages to each other. I implemented ports using vectors. I need a mechanism to store them together, so currently I'm using trait objects that hide the inner type of the vectors.

Comment: *"If users want to use it, then they will need to make sure that their values implement the FromStr"* - that's exactly what happens if you just leave out the second part, just that it's compiler enforced. The method doesn't exist if the type doesn't implement `FromStr`, and it exists if it does. So why do you want to make it a runtime error so that the programmer has to manually ensure that the type implements `FromStr`? Having the compiler check that is far superior and in the spirit of Rust.

Comment: While this is possible with [specialization](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/31844), it does not make sense to me in this circumstance. You'll want to look for a different approach to solving your problem.

Comment: If you really need some sort of dynamic type-checking, you'll want to use [downcasting](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/any/trait.Any.html#method.downcast)

Comment: @NyxCode not to mention specialization is far from being stabilized yet.